# How can I open a URL periodically with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript array:

```
var urls = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.msn.com', 'https://stackoverflow.com'];
```

I am having the array of URLs. I want to open each URL every 15 seconds in a new tab or window.

```
function g(){
  setTimeout(o, 1);
}
function o(){
  window.open('page.php');
}
```

The above code is not working.

Comment: In what way is it not working? Where are you calling `g()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are finding `setInterval`.

```
var urls     = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.msn.com', 'https://stackoverflow.com'];
var index    = 0;
var interval = setInterval(o, 15000);

function o() {
    if (typeof urls[index] !== typeof undefined) {
        window.open(urls[index]);
        index++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jaydeep_Mor/z7q5ovxp/9/)